# Aligning items inside my TableRow

Tags: android, xml, alignment, tablerow

I have a TableRow which has four text views.I'm trying to align the items inside my tablerow. When the string of item 1(TextView) is long, it pushes the item 2. I tried setting android:layout_weight="1" equally but that didn't work. Is there a way I can align the items?

[image]

This is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/product_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_background"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            style="@style/product_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_id"
            style="@style/product_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_quantity"
            style="@style/product_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_value_amt"
            style="@style/product_row"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/product_row_value"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/employee_header"
        style="@style/product_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_header"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/crew" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_header"
        style="@style/product_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_header"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/quantity_sold" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/sales_report_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey_light"
        />
    <TextView
        style="@style/product_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/black_font" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any comments/help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This may help you.

Here is my sample code.

```
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/product_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_value_amt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the TableRow inside a TableLayout and used the following to align my tablerow.

```
android:shrinkColumns="0"
android:stretchColumns="*" // Inside TableLayout.
```

I also added a

```
android:weightSum="10"
```

and divided my tablerows equally using the android:layout_weight attribute. This gave my textView equal margins. Playing with android:layout_weight helped me in dividing the columns equally.